# How to pass in img src in vue.js using props?

Tags: vue.js

I have an `info-card.vue` component that is used twice in a landing page, but I want different data displayed in each of them. Here is the `info-card.vue` component:

```html
<template>
    <div class="card-container glass-effect">
        <div class="illustration-container">
            <img src="{{ image }}" alt="Businesses" class="illustration">
        </div>

        <div class="title-container">{{ title }}</div>

        <div class="paragraph-container">{{ content }}</div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: ['image','title', 'content']
}
</script>
```

And here is the `landing-info.vue` page that the `info-card` component is used in:

```html
<div class="business-side">
    <info-card image="/images/image1.png" title="BUSINESSES" content="This is some content"></info-card>
</div>

<div class="customer-side">
    <info-card image="/images/image2.png" title="CUSTOMERS" content="This is some content"></info-card>
</div>
```

But this didn't work, I'm new to vue so any ideas?

Comment: `:src="image"`. The colon is important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use mustache {{   }} in vue attributes. Instead use `v-bind:attr=""` or `:attr=""` where `attr` is the dynamic attribute you want to bind.

So, your image component should be:

```html
<img v-bind:src="image" alt="Businesses" class="illustration" />
```

or

```html
<img :src="image" alt="Businesses" class="illustration">
```

The colon is a shorthand for v-bind.
Read more on [v-bind here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind).